# jquery file upload to tornado web server with different domain

Tags: jquery, file-upload, subdomain, tornado

im trying to use [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to post files to a fileserver written in tornado.
while i can post a file to the same domain i have issues if my fileserver is on a different domain or a subdomain of the origin. lets say from mydomain.com to files.mydomain.com

on the tornado web handler i set up an OPTIONS and a POST handler. the options function looks like this:

```
def options(self):
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS')
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 1000)
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
    self.set_status(200)
```

in the console i get a

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://files.mycomain.com/upload. Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

but the response shows that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set to *.

how can i make this thing work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly send ajax requests across domains due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If you want to upload a file to a different domain, you'll need the server (on the same domain) to act as a proxy for the upload.

#### See also:

- [Same origin policy for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)
- [Use a Web Proxy for Cross-Domain XMLHttpRequest Calls](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)
- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: For the same reason. You can use the `document.domain` workaround described in the other q&a I linked.

Comment: the issue im having right now is that my app is on GAE and i need to store big files (even 500mb and more). i didn't want to use the blobstore to keep those huge files. i cant even use a proxy like [downy](http://code.google.com/p/downy/) to redirect the request body to my fileserver cause of the 10sec urlfetch limit. i wont be able to send a 600mb files within those seconds.